# Image upload error using HTmlExtendEditor

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Ajax htmleditorextender to upload a image.
In local solution, able to upload the image successfully.

Once I published into IIS, Image upload is not happening.

Please Find the attached Screenshot for the same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAPZV.jpg)

Comment: What version of Ajax Control Toolkit do you use?

Comment: I am using v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0):

It seems you set up AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd incorrectly.

Please make sure it is located at the root path of the web site or adjust AjaxFileUploadHandler path in Web.config accordingly.

Here is the relevant issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues/43#issuecomment-203889967